# SP2010 Default Application not available after new Web Application was made / deleted

Tags: 2010, web-application

I have a SharePoint 2010 test environment was working perfectly with it's default Web Application and root site.  This is a single server install, with its own local copy of SQL.

I've made and deleted a few additional Web Applications for various purposes.  These have been deleted with no problems.  However, my last one somehow has the same Port Number as the default web application.  Nowe my default site doesn't work.  I've deleted the web app with the same port number to no success.  I've also additionally restarted IIS (with and without /noforce) and restarted the box.

My main app still doesn't want to work.  I'm uncertain as to why.  Any suggestions / tips on what to do or check would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok well as you said that you had two web apps using the same port?

You need to check the host header file and DNS.

dns can be found in admin tools and host header is located under windows folder that you would need to search for! cant remember off the top of me head!

Is the site under SSL?

Comment: This hit me as soon as I posted.  I set the binding in IIS and it seemed to work after another reset.

Comment: bingo ;) , for some reason sharepoint has a habbit of removing bindings! I was going to point to IIS if you said yes to SSL as you need to state the host header SSL port ect